# scailing hover effect doesn't work, Chrome

Tags: css

If you take a look at this page with FF: http://wearewebstars.dk/referencer.aspx, then you will see a hover effect on the images on the bottom, but in Chrome, it doesn't work, cant quite figure out why ?

The code in pretty straight forward and Chrome, should be able to understand the "scale" ?

```
.case-item img {
width:100%;
height:auto;
```

}

.case-item  .img-thumb img {
    opacity: 0.25;
}

.case-item  .img-thumb:hover img {
    opacity: 0.6;
    transform: scale(1.3) rotate(10.5deg);
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the -webkit- prefix, source: http://caniuse.com/#search=transform